# How to register dependency for signalr hub using TinyIocContainer within NancyFx

Tags: signalr, ioc-container, signalr-hub, nancy, tinyioc

I'm a little new to NancyFx and TinyIoc, but here goes:

I have been able to use auto registration of TinyIocContainer within NanxyFx to inject dependencies in Nancy Modules which is very neat, thats all fine and working.

But, **how do you register a dependency for a signalr hub like below?**

I am constantly getting the classic error message from signalr:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

**My setup:**

I have a SignalR Hub:

```
[Hubname("chathub")]
public class ChatHub: Hub {

    private IChat _chat;

    public ChatHub(Chat chat){
      _chat = chat;
    }

}
```

This is my dependency:

```
public class Chat: IChat{

    public Chat(IHubConnectionContext clients, IChatRepo repo){
       ...
    }
}
```

I have created a CustomBootstrapper class:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
        // I'm hoping the registration below will resolve for the IHubConnectionContext parameter for the Chat class
        container.Register(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>().Clients);
    }
}
```

I have a startup class:

```
 public class Startup{
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true};
    app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);
 }
```

If I have a parameterless constructor for the ChatHub and use poor mans Ioc, everything works fine.

I am pretty certain I am missing something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The following article should give you the information you need to use dependency injection with SignalR:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection

The "Simple Dependency Injection in SignalR" section shows you how "you can easily register a function to create hub instances, and use this function to perform DI."

The article continues to show you can go even further and replace SignalR's dependency resolver with your own IoC container such as TinyIoC (though the article uses Ninject as an example).

Comment: Thanks for the article. - I just created a custom DependencyResolver, but I'm not entirely sure set the Resolver. e.g. in the article it sets the customer resolver via the HubConfiguration. Where as in within Nancy, I have a CustomBootstrapper which inherits from DefaultNancyBootstrapper and I on the ApplicationStartup overload, do I set the Resolver there via something like: GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new TinyIoCDependencyResolver(container)?? I've tried both, but to no avail.

Comment: Not sure if it was left out for brevity but your Startup class has no `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method as per the article linked above.  Not sure if with your stack Owin is still involved but in my MVC5 app there is also the following assembly directive:
`[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Namespace.Of.Startup))]`